# K-mean mean distance

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was trying to use K-means in order to find outliers. I have used the elbow-method of the optimal k and found out it is k=3.

I wanted to find the distance between a cluster centroid and the data points, and if that distance is larger than the 2*std of the mean distance to the centorid then it should be conisdered as an outlier

I'm struggling to implement the part that defines if  2*std the mean distance is smaller than the distance between data points and the centroid that is considered as an outlier.

I thought of defining a column with, distance = 2*std mean distance - distance to a centroiod, and the rows that have negative values for a distance could be dropped.

I will show the code I currently have ( which I'm pretty sure is not correct), I will also post an error I keep getting for the centroid.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances


df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Final After Simple Filtering.csv')

del df['MeasuredYawError']
del df['NacelleOrientation_Deg']
del df['Pitch_Deg']





KMEAN = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(df)

Centroid = KMEAN.cluster_centers_

for (data,cind) in zip(df.get_values(),KMEAN):
    distance = euclidean_distances(Centriod[cind],data)



Centroid_std= 2*Centoid.std()
Inliner= Centroid_std - distance
df=df[df['Inliner'] == Inliner>=0]
del df['inliner']

plt.scatter( df['WindSpeed_mps'], df['Power_kW'], label='Measurements',s=1)
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6b3df6c4c307> in <module>()
     24 KMEAN = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(df)
     25 
---> 26 Centroid = KMEAN.cluster_centers_
     27 
     28 for (data,cind) in zip(df.get_values(),KMEAN):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'
```

**Can someone help me to achieve the above described goal?**

Comment: Can you give an example for your csv?

Comment: My csv consists of 13 columns and 10.1 million rows, but I have created a sample of 100,000 rows.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-BMglNntth3ZRfPrGBWeLl-5DOjwvlhP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Scott do you mean,  if the distance is bigger than 3sd or 2sd of the mean distance it can be considered as an outlier?

Comment: Not exactly.  If you sum the squares of the distances, then square root that and divide by `n`, you get a sort of multidimensional analogue of the standard deviation.  Specifically, it is the entries of the covariance matrix where the off-diagonal entries are constrained to be 0 and the diagonal is constrained to be all identical values.  In any case, you can use that value similarly to how you would use the standard deviation to find outliers in other datasets, by looking some number of them away from the mean, which would be the centroid.

Comment: So I can use the k-mean inertia function to implement that? Sorry but what is `n`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you try to do to find the outliers really make sense in Kmeans. Kmeans find the centroids, by an EM process, and set the centroids to be the mean of each group fo the data. if each point is then nearer to one centroid than others, it will move to that cluster.

The way you want to define the outliers, I am not sure if scientifically makes sense, but I am not a pro in clustering. Anyway, if you want to calculate the distance, `KMEAN.fit_predict(df)` will give you a list of N indices( where N is the number of data you have), where each index is 0,1 or 2 because you have set K=3.

`Centriod=KMEAN.cluster_centers_` will return a list of 3 tuples of centroids, where each centroid is a tuple of size M, where M is the dimension of each data you have( you have m features).

So what you really actually need is to go over each data:

```
clusters_inds=KMEAN.fit_predict(df)
for (data,cind) in zip(df.get_values(),clusters_inds):
    distance = euclidean_distances(Centriod[cind],data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm aware that Kmean is not really efficienct or effective when finding outliers but I'm trying it to compare it with algorithims that are meant to find outliers for example Isolation Forest (Which gave really good results). I'm extremely sorry since I'm new too all of this, from my understand of your code this will find the distance of each point to the closest cluster centroid?

Comment: No worries. No, my point is not about if Kmeans is good for outliers or not. I meant, the centroids are already the mean of the clusters. for a data d, you count the distance form the centroid, you are actually computing the distance from the mean, it does not make sense to substract again the result from the mean. It will be like: `|m-d|-m` , it does not waht you want. However you can check if the distance from the mean is greater than like 2*STD of the cluster or not, and that is a way to get your anomalies

Comment: Ahh, so from my understand `Centriod=KMEAN.cluster_centers_` is actually the mean distance. and after the code you posted, is the distance of each datapoint with the centroid? Also if you don't mind of course can we start a chat on stackoverflow?